# How to validate x509 signing credentials with IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have two .Net Core APIs - an authorization server that issues a JWT identity token using IdentityServer4, and a resource API that is protected and requires that token.

The auth server is using a self-signed x509 certificate (for now).

In the the auth server I have something like this in `ConfigureServices`:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2(//path.to.my.certificate//);
services.AddIdentityServer().AddSigningCredential(certificate)
```

But my understanding of how the resource API will validate the signing credentials is not clear.

All I have in `ConfigureServices` for the resource API is:

```
services.AddAuthentication(IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(
                    options =>
                    {
                        options.Authority = "//MyAuthAPI";
                    });
```

Should the resource API use the same certificate to validate the JWT token? Is that necessary?

If so, how should that be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the ASP.Net Core middleware downloads the identity provider configuration from `https://{yourDomain}/.well-known/openid-configuration` which is your `options.Authority` uri. If you actually navigate to one sub url `https://{yourDomain}/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwks`, you will also see that identity provider publishes the public key that it uses to sign the tokens.

With the public key acquired, the middleware is able to verify that the tokens were indeed issue by the expected authority uri using the headers (`Authorize : Bearer {token}`) included in the api requests using regular asymmetric encryption verification methods.

Comment: In case of Javascript client, is there any library that would do the similar verification?